# настройка путей в cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, git, cakephp

После клонирования из гит-репозитория сайта написанного на СakePHP, изображения добавленные через хелпер `$this->Html->image()` подгружаются нормально (`site/img/pic.png`). Изображения добавленные стандартным способом вместо корректного пути ищутся в `/img/pic.png` и ожидаемо не находятся. Где нужно поковыряться, чтобы изображения брались из правильной директории?

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему следующим образом:
в hosts добавил строчку

```
127.0.0.1       localhost my_site
```

В файл `C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.conf` добавил:

```
<VirtualHost my_site:80>

    DocumentRoot "c:/Apache24/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName my_site
    <directory "c:/wamp64/www/my_site">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp64/www/my_site"

</VirtualHost>
```